# Want to start new Activity on Login completion

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

I want to start a new activity when Facebook login completes that happens in a DialogListener. Login done successfully No error comes but activity doesn't start. If you require logcat I can email you.
Following is my code.

**Here is My HomeActivity**

```
package com.example.faceb;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private static final String TAG = "Facebook";
    private Button mLogin, mLogout, mShare;
    private Facebook facebook;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner abRunner;

    public boolean flag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        facebook = new Facebook("479652662068145");
        abRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        mLogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
        mLogout= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Logout);

        mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLogout.setOnClickListener(this);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        int id = v.getId();
        switch(id){
            case R.id.Login:
                FacebookLoginDialog login = new FacebookLoginDialog(this);         
                facebook.authorize(this, login);
                if (func()==true)         
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.Logout:
                FacebookLogoutRequest logout = new FacebookLogoutRequest(this);
                abRunner.logout(this, logout);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "You Are Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static boolean func() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**And Following my FacebookLoginDialog Class**

```
public class FacebookLoginDialog implements DialogListener{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        HomeActivity.func();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

This dialog starts on a button click which is in my `HomeActivity`. Please help I searched a lot and tried but unable to solve this issue.

Comment: put a log inside **onComplete()** and check whether it is firing..

Comment: Instead of getApplicationContext() you should try your Activity context. getApplicationContext() is tricky sometimes.

Comment: @ Andro I have tried Activity context also.

Comment: Put this line *Log.e("Check", "your message");*. Also put this line in all your other methods and check your logcat output. See which one is firing. This way you know either your login is completed successfully or there is any error in it.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: add a breakpoint in your onComplete function (which is the one triggered once the login process works) and inspect the context variable.. Probably it's not correct.

Comment: @RKN can you give your email where i can share my error logcat with you to help me. I am new in this field so I couldn't understand the error

Comment: why can't you paste your logcat here??

Comment: I cant because my reputation is below 10 and i cant answer my own question . And in comments only 500 characters are allowed.

Comment: paste your logcat with the question.

Comment: @RKN I have pasted the logcat please take a look and tell me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of starting the dialog on button click, u can start the activity, which u want to start after login. Then call the dialog inside the `onCreate()` of the new activity. So that u can just close the dialog in `onComplete()` and automatically the new screen will appear. Just keep a flag in the activity and set it to true only when the login succeeds. So that u can finish the new activity if the flag is false after the dialog get closed.

Comment: yes I understood what you are saying but I don't want to do it like this.

Comment: ok then dont go to the next activity, u can do the same logic in ur home screen itself. Keep a flag and make it true when login succeeds. Then after the dialog closes just check the flag and go to the new activity if it is true.

Comment: I will try that if I didn't find solution. Can you understand the error in above logcat

Comment: it is related to the library u r using for the facebook app.. Sorry I am not able to spot you the error exactly.. :(

Comment: Its ok Anu how will I do it with flag?

Comment: declare a boolean variable (falg) in your home activity. Then set it true when the login succeeds else set it as false and close the dialog. then check the flag and if it is true start a new activity.

Comment: Only this way remain suitable..I couldn't start the activity on login completion.. Thanks Anu

Answer (score 1):

First of all are you properly logged in?

Try the following:

1) Comment the code in the `onComplete()` method and just put a log message.

2) You should preferably use the authorize method which takes 3 parameters `facebook.authorize(context,permission[],listener)`

3) to check whether you are properly logged in use `facebook.isSessionValid() { // log a msg}`

You MUST be able to see the msg in the above block... only then start the new Activity

4) Also if you can post ur MainActivity , we can answer better....

Comment: I have also shared homeActivity can you take a look and tell me where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use getApplicationContext in your onComplete to get the context, your problem will be solved.
Code will be like

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

I have checked it, it works fine...

```
if(access_token != null) {
                    facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                }
                if(expires != 0) {
                    facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
                }

                //if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

                facebook.authorize((Activity) ctx, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posting To Your Wall !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.d("Graph Api", "Posting To Wall");
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                                R.drawable.icon);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                            byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

                            String response = facebook.request("me");
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("message", "" + edt.getText().toString() + "...");
                            parameters.putByteArray("picture", bitMapData);
                            response = facebook.request("photos", parameters, 
                                    "POST");
                            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                                    response.equals("false")) {
                               Log.v("Post Error", "Error Occured While Posting in Facebook");
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured While Posting in Facebook !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            else {
                                Log.v("Post Success", "Posting Succesful in Facebook");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posting Succesful in Facebook !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                edt.setText("");
                            }

                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured While Authenticating in Facebook !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.v("FaceBook Error", ""+error);                      
                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DiaLogError Occured While Authenticating in Facebook !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.v("DialogError","" + e);
                    }

                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Have Canceled !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                //}
            }
```

Comment: thanks chinmoy when i use getApplication context it gives error in that line

Comment: it gives error getApplicationContext(); is undefined for the type FacebookLoginDialog

Comment: i have edited my answer man , you can check it now.
You can also get help from here -- https://github.com/chinmoy12/Experiment-Project/tree/master/Exp_Fb_Twt

Answer (score 0):

You can not fire a activity using Intent in nonUIThread. You should use callback function in onComplete()which you notify that user logout or login successfully.Then after you call your Intent in Activity with the help of callback function..

Comment: I have understood the error.  But can't really think how would i use call back function in onComplete()

Comment: Make method in Activity which fire your intent.Then After call this method in your onComplete() or your should use interface.

Comment: Hi Rishabh I have edited my above code check it. It is not helping

Comment: i havc edited your code use this & let me know if you still facing issue.

Comment: I have used your code but small errors. in static function I can not use this and startActivity (non static refrences). And if i change to non static then i can't access it in another class

Comment: I think onComplete method is not working maybe. Should i give you logcat? Many thanks for your help